# Bootstrap modal seems disabled on ios device

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, bootstrap-modal

i bought quick-admin template. I use bootstrap modal, it's okay with PC and android, windows phone but on iOS device all input tags in modal seems disabled and i can't edit inputs. But other templates it works fine. Please can anyone tell what is problem? maybe js or css prevent it. have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be confusion of js files, remove ids of div form step by step and you can find problem.

Comment: thank you very muck, i spent a lot of time for this problem. i delete id="wrapper" attribute of div and it works fine. thanks a lot